# Pervasive SQL order by with if

Tags: sql, pervasive, actian

In Pervasive SQL 11 I could use a IF statement in the ORDER BY:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
    D1001 as 'part_number', 
    '' as 'required_date', 
    '' as 'confirmed_date'
    FROM PULAGER 
    WHERE 
    D1001 LIKE '1121%' 
    
    UNION 
    
    SELECT 
    D5410 as 'part_number', 
    D5511 as 'required_date', 
    D5513 as 'confirmed_date'
    FROM PUIKOKRO 
    WHERE 
    D5410 LIKE '1121%' 
) as t1
ORDER BY part_number, IF (confirmed_date = '', required_date, confirmed_date)
```

But after an upgrade version 15.10.031, I get the error "Reference to column name not allowed in ORDER BY with UNION". No error if I remove the IF statement. Any suggestions?

First order by part_number and then order by required_date or confirmed_date depending on the state of confirmed_date.

Comment: What error are you getting?  Are you using v15 SP1 or the original v15?  I tried it using v15 SP1, and didn't get any errors.

Comment: The error was something like "reference to column not allowed in order by with union". But I only have the UNIONs inside a subquery and the ORDER BY in the outer query. The error disappeared when I removed the IF statement.
Do you know how to get version information via ODBC?

Comment: The exact error message was "Reference to column name not allowed in ORDER BY with UNION".

Comment: forgot @mirtheil in my previous comments

Comment: What's the rest of your SQL?  What shows in the Help | About, specifically the "Zen Install Version", in the Zen Control Center?

Comment: @mirtheil I have updated the question with a complete SQL and version (15.10.031).

Comment: With your full SQL, I can confirm the behavior you are seeing.  I would suggest contacting Actian and opening a support ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by moving the IF statement to the SELECT to create a new column 'sort_date' and wrapping it all with another SELECT. Doesn't feel like the most beautiful solution, but it works.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t1.*, IF (confirmed_date = '', required_date, confirmed_date) as 'sort_date' FROM t1
) ORDER BY part_number, sort_date
```